# How to show that this numerical differentation formula for the 4th derivative converges?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have to show that the numerical differentation formula
$$ f^\left(IV\right) (x) = \frac{1}{h^4} \left(f(x-2h)-4f(x-h)+6f(x)-4f(x+h)+f(x+2h)\right) + R_h(f) $$

converges.

How do I do that? Do I have to show something related to the truncation error $R_h(f) $ ?

Comment: Use the taylor expansion of all the $f$?

Comment: The question is precisely to show that the truncation error tends to zero !

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $f$ at $x$,
$$f(x+kh)=f(x)+f'(x)(kh)+\frac{f''(x)}{2}(kh)^2+\frac{f'''(x)}{6}(kh)^3+\frac{f^{iv}(x)}{24}(kh)^4+o(h^4)$$
with $k=\pm1$ and  $k=\pm2$.
Now
$$\Delta_1:=f(x+h)+f(x-h)=2f(x)+2\frac{f''(x)}{2}(h)^2+2\frac{f^{iv}(x)}{24}(h)^4+o(h^4).$$
Similarly
$$\Delta_2:=f(x+2h)+f(x-2h)=2f(x)+2\frac{f''(x)}{2}(2h)^2+2\frac{f^{iv}(x)}{24}(2h)^4+o(h^4).$$
Then
$$f(x-2h)-4f(x-h)+6f(x)-4f(x+h)+f(x+2h)=\Delta_2-4\Delta_1+6f(x)\\ =2f(x)+4f''(x)h^2+\frac{32f^{iv}(x)}{24}h^4
-8f(x)-4f''(x)h^2-\frac{8f^{iv}(x)}{24}h^4+6f(x)+o(h^4)$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{(32-8)f^{iv}(x)}{24}h^4+o(h^4)=f^{iv}(x)+o(h^4).$$

Comment: Not sure. Expanding everything I get $$ f^\left(IV\right) (x) = \frac{0}{h^4} + + R_h(f) $$ . I'm guessing the fourth derivatives should add up to 1, thus showing that $R_h(f) =0 $ ?

Comment: @peeter pats See my edited answer. It seems that everything works.

Comment: I think I got it now, thanks!

Comment: @peeter pats Well done! BTW, if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour